# How to OR multiple entries in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

SELECT url FROM `table` WHERE scategory LIKE 'entertainment' or 'educational'

This query doesn't throw any error but it only throws only 'entertainment' subcategories. How can I get both of the subcategories?

Comment: @Mustafa, in such case it's better to use `IN` operator

Comment: @Sagar Pawar please don't make major edits to the question, once it has been answered, to the extent that it becomes completely different from the original. This will cause confusion and render the question and answers useless. Please consider starting a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's a wired condition in `WHERE` clause ... it has to be like below. You can't punch in single `LIKE` operator for all columns like that *One For All*

```
WHERE description like '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
or scategory like '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
or category like '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
```

Comment: @SagarPawar, then consider accepting the answer by clicking the check button

Answer (score 0):

The attributes need to be seperated to individually check for the Like pattern else it just takes the one previous to the Like condition , in your case , category. The code should be :

```
   SELECT * FROM `table` 
   WHERE description like '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
   or scategory like '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
   or category like '%".$_POST["search"]."%'
```

Hope it clears your doubt